# Not able to solve passport-saml req.isAuthenticated() false issue

Tags: node.js, passport-saml

I'm new to saml and using Nodejs + Express + passport-saml + okta identity provider. I know this is a duplicate question but somehow I am not able to solve this by looking lot of threads on the internet.

I used yeoman express generator for project. Here are my settings:

Server is behind ngnix using https. So, if I hit https://mywebsite.com, it redirects internally to localhost:3000 on that server.

### express.js

```
var samlUtil = require('./saml-util.js');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '2mb',
    extended: true
}));
app.use(compress());
app.use(cookieParser(config.SERVER_KEYS.SERVER_SECRET));
app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use(session({
    secret: config.SERVER_KEYS.SERVER_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        expires: false,
        secure: true
    }
}));

app.use(samlUtil.initialize());
app.use(samlUtil.session());

app.get('/saml/response', samlUtil.protected, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Hello " + req.session.passport.user);
});

app.get('/saml/invalid', function(req, res) {
    res.end("Authentication failed");
});

app.post('/saml/callback', samlUtil.authenticate('saml', {
    failureRedirect: '/saml/response/',
    failureFlash: true
}), function(req, res) {
    req.session.save(function() {
        res.redirect('/saml/response/');
    })
});

app.get('/saml/login', samlUtil.authenticate('saml', {
    failureRedirect: '/saml/response/',
    failureFlash: true
}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/saml/response/');
});
```

### saml-util.js

```
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var root = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../..');
var constant = require(root + '/app/util/constants.js');

var config = require(constant.APP_CONFIG_FILE);
var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

var users = [];

function findByEmail(email, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        if (user.email === email) {
            return fn(null, user);
        }
    }
    return fn(null, null);
}

// Passport session setup.
//   To support persistent login sessions, Passport needs to be able to
//   serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  Typically,
//   this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
//   the user by ID when deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializing');
    done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('de-serializing');
    findByEmail(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new SamlStrategy({
    issuer: config.SAML.ISSUER_URL,
    path: config.SAML.PATH,
    entryPoint: config.SAML.ENTRY_POINT,
    cert: config.SAML.CERTIFICATE,
}, function(profile, done) {
    console.log('got profile');
    console.log(profile);

    if (!profile.email) {
        return done(new Error("No email found"), null);
    }

    process.nextTick(function() {
        console.log('Finding by email');

        findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log('new user');
                users.push(profile);
                return done(null, profile);
            }
            console.log('existing user');
            return done(null, user);
        })
    });
}));

passport.protected = function protected(req, res, next) {
    console.log('is isAuthenticated =' + req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/saml/invalid');
};

exports = module.exports = passport;
```

What is happening:

1. I can hit the URL:  /saml/login
2. Gets redirected to the okta login page (where I have identity settings)
3. I login successfully
4. I'm redirected to the URL: /saml/callback with response:

   ```
   {issuer:
       { _: 'http://www.okta.com/exkctyzcknbMikNjl0h7',
         '$': 
          { Format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity',
            'xmlns:saml2': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion' } },
      sessionIndex: '_3acb290873febaf825cd',
      nameID: 'ashutosh@myemail.com',
      nameIDFormat: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
      nameQualifier: undefined,
      spNameQualifier: undefined,
      firstName: 'Ashutosh',
      lastName: 'Pandey',
      email: 'ashutosh@myemail.com',
      getAssertionXml: [Function] }
   ```

In the /saml/callback URL, I can see value returned in req.user but
 req.isAuthenticated() in saml-util is always returning false.

Comment: (Aside: there are two ways to format code immediately following a list item. If it is meant to be part of the list item, indent it twice - this is the official Markdown way. If it is meant to follow the whole list, then put a `<!-- comment -->` after the list, which confuses the parser enough to render the code separate from the list).

Comment: ok thanks halfer :)

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever resolve it?